# Docker container has unexpected directory structure

Tags: macos, docker, docker-for-mac

I am experiencing a strange behaviour using Docker for Mac:

1. I downloaded and ran a docker image A on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine with Docker 17.03.1-ce installed on it. When I examine the directory structure of the resulting container, everything is ok.
2. I downloaded and ran the same docker image A on my personal Mac (MacOS Sierra 10.12.5 with Docker for Mac 17.06.0-ce installed on it). When I examine the directory structure of the resulting container, **it does not match the expected directory structure of the container running on the Ubuntu 16.04 machine (see point 1 above). In fact, some files have been placed directly under the root directory ("/") instead of being placed under the right sub folders**. As a result, my application does not start because these files are "missing" (more precisely, the files do not exist at the expected location).

Extra info:

- I used the same docker command to run the containers on both machines. This command did not contain any extra options (ie, no volume was mounted).
- The image I ran is a custom image with a "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.3" operating system and JBoss running on it. This image was built on Docker 1.10.3.

Does somebody have an idea about this issue? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try building the image on Mac?

Comment: The problem is that, for some compatibility reason, the image must be built using a Docker version 1.10, and I do not immediately have access to a Mac with Docker version 1.10 installed on it. I could downgrade the Docker version on my computer but as we are not sure that this would solve the problem, I would prefer to avoid this. Anyway, many thanks for you suggestion.

Comment: I doubt Docker for Mac will have that old version. Open a issue with Docker Mac as well

Comment: This was in fact a known issue and will be fixed in a next version. See https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1934. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks for sharing